# Resolving apt-get dependency problem

Tags: boot, apt, dependencies

I've got a stuck package system, due to the issue of trying to clean out /boot so updates will happen.  Right now I am at the point where:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Fails because it tries to install a package, which gets a /boot disk full error.  Trying to remove packages does not work:

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-97-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-generic : Depends: linux-signed-image-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have enough space for the new Linux Kernel, so you have to delete the old one.

First, run this command:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
```

This will show you what packages will be removed. Make sure your current kernel version is not in that list. Run `uname -a` to see what your kernel version is.

Next, run this command to remove each of them using `dpkg --remove`. You could also just copy the name in the first section before the `dpkg --remove` command.

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs dpkg --remove
```

Finally, you will be able to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.